# where is the definition of “Struct OrtSession” in OnnxRutime source code。

Tags: c++

when I use OnnxRutime c/c++ API, I can't find the definition of “Struct OrtSession” in the source code; only the forward declaration。

[ONNXruntime github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime)

Comment: Could you post some code that results in this error.

Comment: Who says there is more than a forward declaration? It could be an opaque type. In any case, since you already mistyped `struct` with an uppercase `S`, I wonder if you searched the sourcecode using a tool or just browsed it manually? Just to avoid the confusion, I don't want to sound condescending, it just makes me wonder that you share so little of what you already tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: sorry, I  mistyped `struct` with an uppercase `S`. But the definition of OrtSession is still not found. As you mentioned，It could be an opaque type. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.